# Devilbox laravel register page throws 502 but works after refresh

Tags: php, laravel, lamp

I have setup laravel on devilbox and I'm creating my first application using this tutorial: https://auth0.com/blog/creating-your-first-laravel-app-and-adding-authentication/

I have setup laravel auth and the login page works but when I click on either 'register' or 'recover password' it throws 502 error. What makes it weird is if I refresh the page with the 502 error it loads fine but every time I either click the faulty links or copy the links on another tab/borwser it throws the 502 first time and then work after refresh.

What might be causing that and how do I fix it? Is it a problem maybe with my dns records setup? I have in my `/etc/hosts` file `127.0.0.1 my-laravel.loc` line, is that correct?

I don't know what code to post, because I'm so new to laravel so if you need to see some code from my view or routes or whatever just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your .env file to get link with the database.